# How to apply security patch in SharePoint 2010 without upgrading to cumulative update?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, security

Microsoft releases security bulletin every month which also include SharePoint vulnerabilities.

We have many sites running on my SharePoint 2010 instance, and if we apply cumulative update according to Microsoft release note, every months, so there will be interruption on running sites which we dont want.

Kindly share your thought on below,

1. Do we have anyway to update only security patch instead of cumulative update of SharePoint?
2. Will these security patches be sufficient for all known vulnerabilities according to Microsoft Bulletin?

Comment: installing the security patch will also interrup the service

Answer (score 0):

1. You can apply the security-only update but it’ll require the same downtime as a CU
2. Yes.  SP2010 is in security-only support.  That said, security updates aren’t cumulative.  CUs are.  So unless you’re applying these security updates every month, it’d be best to stick with the CUs.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Greg, Here is an article about SharePoint Patching Best Practices for your reference:

https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2020/02/11/sharepoint-patching-best-practices/